# Alternative to SAFE_OFFSET to pull out info from an ARRAY in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In a database table where some categorical values and tallies of those values are stored in arrays, how do I pull out the tally of a single categorical value stored in an array like below?

I.e. assume I want to tally the amount of people feeling sad in the example below. I have attempted doing so with SAFE_OFFSET, but it fails when one value is missing in the array meaning the position if "sad" is changed, see ie on the row containing the date 2020-01-03. Is there a good way to SELECT based on the name of the category instead (emotion.state)?

```
SELECT 
  date,
  emotion[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] emotion
FROM `feelings_database`
```

Sample table:

```
date        emotion.state  emotion.people
2020-01-01  happy          10
            ok             15
            sad            7
2020-01-02  happy          1
            ok             20
            sad            2
2020-01-03  ok             10
            sad            20
2020-01-04  happy          30
            ok             5
2020-02-05  happy          20
            ok             30
            sad            100
```

Intended output:

```
date       people_sad
2020-01-01 7
2020-01-02 2
2020-01-03 20
2020-01-04 null
2020-01-05 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good way to SELECT based on the name of the category instead (emotion.state)?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, 
  ( SELECT people 
    FROM t.emotion 
    WHERE state = 'sad'
  ) AS people_sad
FROM `project.dataset.feelings_database` t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row date        people_sad   
1   2020-01-01  7    
2   2020-01-02  2    
3   2020-01-03  20   
4   2020-01-04  null     
5   2020-02-05  100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest()`:

```
select fd.date, em.people as people_sad
from `feelings_database` fd left join
     unnest(fd.emotion) as em
     on em.state = 'sad';
```